# What could cause eslint-plugin-prettier to report error on CircleCI but be silent locally?

Tags: eslint, circleci, prettier

I have to migrate from CircleCI 1.0 to 2.0. After I have changed the old configuration to the new one, build failed because of eslint-plugin-prettier reported prettier spacing violations.

MyProject - is my GitHub repo and it contains a folder `client` which has all front-end code which I want to build on CI. In `client` folder there are

**.eslintrc.json**

```
...
"extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
"plugins": ["prettier"],
...
```

**.prettierrc**

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

**.gitattributes** (I work on Windows 10) with the following code:

```
*.js text eol=crlf
*.jsx text eol=crlf
```

and of course package.json

[image]

New CircleCI configuration:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/MyProject
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:6.14.3-jessie-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Packages
          command: npm install
          working_directory: client
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: npm run validate
          working_directory: client
```

Old CircleCI configuration:

```
## Customize dependencies
machine:
  node:
    version: 6.1.0

 # Remove cache before new build. It takes much time
 # but fixing a build which is broken long time ago (and not detected because of cache)  
 # is even more time consuming
dependencies:
  post:
   - rm -r ~/.npm 

## Customize test commands
test:
  override:
    - npm run validate

general:
  build_dir: client
```

The build fails due to linting problems (all are about the number of spaces):

[image]

So, what could cause these errors? I am out of ideas here. I first thought it might be because .prettierrc was not found. However, when I deleted it for an experiment and run locally I got errors in all files in total more than 1000. While on CI with .prettierrc in place there are were only 188 in few files.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? We are having pretty much the same issue. Local config + pretty-quick doesn't behave the same way in local, as does the linting on CircleCI.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I also asked on CircleCI forums and no success. We still run v.1. Not sure what to do when it is discontinued. I love Prettier and don't want to give up on it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have finally figured it out.

My `package.json` file contained the following dependency on the Prettier:
`"prettier": "^1.11.1"`.

I had to learn hard way the meaning of this little symbol `^`. It allows installing any version of Prettier which is compatible with `1.11.1`. In my case on CircleCI 2.0 it installed `1.14.2` which adds new features to Prettier.

I believe it did not break on CircleCI version 1.0 and locally because of cached node_modules which contained earlier Prettier versions compatible with `1.11.1`

Here is nice [video](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) about semantic versioning.

Comment: That was also the case for me  This was pretty annoying issue to resolve. Thanks for helping. Why on Earth ^ is default on `yarn add`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the pattern.

The `eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx}` command failed in GitLab CI, but not on local.

When I changed it to `eslint src` it failed both on local and CI.